# It’s Everywhere

Tags: riddle, word

> You see me in a wheel, although I am truly a line;

> I am normally a thought-out part of designs;

> But people debate if I am just in your mind.

---

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you possibly

> COLOR ?

You see me in a wheel,

> A COLOR WHEEL is often used to portray color:
>  [image: color wheel]

although I am truly a line;

> Color is caused by wavelengths of electromagnetic radiation which progress linearly from low to high (a line).
>  Or (unlikely) a reference to the term [color line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_line_(racism))

I am normally a thought-out part of designs;

> Most design processes, web, architecture, print, etc. have color as an integral part of the planning.

But people debate if I am just in your mind.

> It is a common [question](https://www.livescience.com/21275-color-red-blue-scientists.html) regarding whether we all actually see the same colors, or if our perceptions of color are determined by our own individual minds.

Title:

> Yes, color is truly everywhere!  It is difficult to imagine a place without color.  Maybe deep space?  Yet I'd color that black.

Comment: Well done! That is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you possibly

> Time?

You see me in a wheel, although I am truly a line;

> We view time in clocks, which are in a circle, but time is - according to one theory - a line going straight forwards, second after second.

I am normally a thought-out part of designs;

> You take into account how long things will take when planning.

But people debate if I am just in your mind.

> Is time real? Is it an illusion? Does anyone really know?

Comment: Good answer, but that’s not it. It is a ‘similar’ idea though, in a way.